# pyspark vs pandas filtering

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pyspark

I am "translating" pandas code to pyspark. When selecting rows with `.loc` and `.filter` I get different count of rows. What is even more frustrating unlike pandas result, pyspark `.count()` result can change if I execute the same cell repeatedly with no upstream dataframe modifications.
My selection criteria are bellow:

```
# pandas 
pdresult = df.loc[(df.ColA.isna()) & (df.ColB.notna())].shape[0]

#pyspark directly
df1 = df.toPandas()
pysresult= df1.filter((df1.ColA.isNull()) & (df1.ColB.isNotNull())].count()

#pyspark with to_pandas_on_spark
df3 = df1.to_pandas_on_spark()
pysresult2= df3[(df.ColA.isna()) & (df3.ColB.notna())].shape[0]
```

Result is `pysresult == pysresult2' but` pysresult2 != pdresult`and`pysresult != pdresult`
Checking manually rows and tracing if conditions were met shows that pandas selects rows correctly while pyspark omits rows that should have been selected (sees something as null that clearly is not a null)

How do I select rows based on if they are null or not and get the same result as pandas reliably ?

Comment: how was `df1` created? are `df` and `df1` exactly same in terms of row values of those columns?

Comment: I should have added it, simply `df1 = df.toPandas()`

Comment: can you share examples of mismatches you found while manually tracing the issue? in pandas, null might mean a lot of things

Comment: i cannot share the data properly but i've finally found the problem. it was `dropDuplicates` exectuted before filtering was done. this was introducing variability